# How to keep both body and headers from a response when using Reqwest?

Tags: rust, reqwest

```
let req: Request = client.get("https://someaddress").build().unwrap();
let resp = client.execute(req).await.unwrap();
let response_headers = resp.headers();
let response_text = resp.text().await.unwrap(); // cannot move out of `resp` because it is borrowed move out of `resp` occurs here
```

If `text()` and `headers()` both consume the response, how are we to ever get both the response headers and response body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the headers will *not* consume the response, but rather return a reference to the `HeaderMap` stored in the response. But getting the body *will* consume the response meaning any reference to it would be invalid, and thus you get an error trying to keep both.

To keep both, you can simply clone the headers:

```
let response_headers = resp.headers().clone();
```

Or to avoid duplicating data, you can "take" the headers out of the response:

```
let mut resp = client.execute(req).await.unwrap();
let response_headers = std::mem::take(resp.headers_mut());
let response_text = resp.text().await.unwrap();
```

Using [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) will pull the value out of the `&mut` from `.headers_mut()` and leave a default, empty `HeaderMap` in its place.

Either method will mean `response_headers` is no longer referencing the response and you can happily get the body without worry of losing them.

Comment: I suppose you know this because `text` takes `self` which would thus create ownership issues for everything based on the `Response` at which point you could search out mut functions in the docs or use clone.